# Laravel HTTP Post API Route Not Found where It Is Defined

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with HTTP post in laravel where it gives an error

> The POST method is not supported for route api/setting/package.

Actually, it works by using postman.

api.php (route)

```
Route::put('/setting/package', [SettingController::class, 'updatePackage']);
```

Http post code

```
    $base = 'https://' . $website->domain;
    $url = $base . '/api/setting/package';
    $post = [
        'package_type' => $websitePackage->name,
        'max_ad' => $websitePackage->max_ad,
        'max_user' => $websitePackage->max_member,
        'expired_at' => $expired_at,
    ];

    $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ]);

    $response = $response->post($url,$post);
```

Here is the postman result

[image]

I have no idea why it is not supported where I have defined it properly in the api route. Any feedbacks are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: So, you are defining a PUT route, and trying to `post` to it? `$response = $response->post($url,$post);`?

Comment: Ah, that is a stupid mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using "PUT" in Postman, not "POST". To allow POST in Laravel, you need to add ::post routing type.

More you can see here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing

```
Route::post('/setting/package', [SettingController::class, 'updatePackage']);
```

Now you should be able to use both POST and PUT.

Comment: Sure, that is my bad.